# Why is this Regex returning false?

Tags: c#

I'm wondering why this is failing. I got this from StackOverflow earlier and modified it to fit my needs. The goal of this function is to sanitize a string. I'm only interested in alphanumeric with basic punctuation.

```
    public static Boolean IsAlphaNumeric(string text)
    {
        Regex rg = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\"",.;?!']* $");

        return rg.IsMatch(text);
    }
```

I have it check something like "The bla, bla bla" and it returns false. Why is this?

Comment: You have a space at the end so unless your string ends with a literal space, it will fail. Remove the space or use RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace

Comment: I suggest using an online regex tester. Most of them will diagnose/debug your pattern and show you what each individual character/group in your regex matches or expects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a space between your `*` and `$` this means that after validating all of the characters in the string match the set `[a-zA-Z0-9\s\"",.;?!']` it is expecting a space before the end of the string. If you add a space to your test string "The bla, bla bla " it will return `true`